# how to create and add jtable in jframe based on user input as no.of rows ans no.of columns?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have to create a jtabel in the jframe dynamically based on user inputs as no.of rows and no. of columns. for example if input is 2 and 3 , my table should come with 2 rows and 3 columns. i have tried many times and but still i don't get.

Comment: *"i have tried many times and but still i don't get."*  What have you tried, specifically?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show what you've tried and we'll try and assist you in understanding what you're doing wrong and/or give you advice on improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the table like this (snippet from my own code)

```
public void setModel() {
    String[] str = new String[col];    <--- contains the name of each column
    Cell[][] obj = new Cell[row][col]; <--- 2d array for every table cell (Cell is an own class)

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {    <--- init the cells (row and col containing the size of the table)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            obj[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
            str[j] = new String("");
        }
    }

    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(obj, str)); <--- set the model for the table
}
```